# Listbox isn't showing Headers

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, listbox-control

I have a Listbox (go figure), and this listbox is not tied to a RecordSource and is dynamically built based on other control choices, by the end-user.  In the past I haven't had much of a problem with this but with this current dynamic query situation, the columns are not definitively constant.  As the RecordSet being used is a CrossTab query, one quarter the CrossTab query may have 5 columns, the next 8 columns, and the next 3 columns.

Most of the ListBox's I have implemented have had a static amount of columns I can predict, but in this situation I am unable to predict the number of columns consistently.

I have set the `ColumnHeads` property to `Yes`, so thats not an issue and I even reset the `ColumnHeads` property against in VBA before the `AddItem` operation I have setup.

Logic I am using to operate in/around the Listbox in question (lstCategoryPG):

```
If lstCatType.ListIndex >= 0 Then
'Application.Echo False    'Turn off Screen Updating

    Dim crt As String: crt = "crt_CategoryPG"   'Cross-Tab Query
    Dim cttbl As String: cttbl = CreateCTTable(crt) 'Create Table to store the Cross-Tab information
    Dim sql As String: sql = SQLSelect(cttbl)
    Dim flds As DAO.Recordset: Set flds = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    Dim fldwd As String     'Store the Field Width pattern
    fldwd = "0"";0"";2"""   'Handles `tid` and `cid` columns in the ListBox
    'Assign the number of columns based on the number of fields in CTtable
    lstCategoryPG.ColumnCount = flds.Fields.Count

    Dim fld As Long
    For fld = 3 To (flds.Fields.Count - 1)
        fldwd = fldwd & ";.75"""
    Next
    flds.Close: Set flds = Nothing

    lstCategoryPG.ColumnWidths = fldwd

    sql = SQLSelect(cttbl, , ("tid = " & lstCatType.Value))

    lstCategoryPG.Enabled = True
    lstCategoryPG.ColumnHeads = True
    RefreshControl CurrentDb, lstCategoryPG, sql, , False
'Application.Echo True     'Turn Screen Updating back on
End If
```

Comment: What is the question and why do you not wish to use a subform which would be so much easier?

Comment: I need to make the item editable....through popup, since you cant Update singular values displayed in a CrossTab

Comment: Ill be using a popup form to make the edits from the end user and group them logically for the updates.

Comment: You did not like my suggestion for editing items from a crosstab subform?

Comment: I need more time on the implementation and time is not my friend right now

Comment: Subforms are a new concept for me in Access.  Im working on developing a pattern of implementation, just clients time-line and my subform learning time-line are not going to be equal

Comment: Subforms are probably the greatest strength of Access.

Comment: I see the power in them, just need to play/break with them, before i can fully utilize them.  Had the similar problems with Collections in .Net.  Knew how to utilize Arrays and do some crazy things with em.  But after I dove into Collections and learned how to manipulate them, i threw Array's to the curb.

Comment: _I need to make the item editable_ From your code it looks as though you are copying your crosstab query result into a table and then using this, sure enough that table will be editable, but will not update the live data from which the crosstab was originally produced, am I missing something?

Comment: @MattDonnan Nope, This situation is a fluid one, i keep changing my design deployment almost daily on this subset of data.  Originally, it was a SubForm implementation.  Now i have it implemented as a ListBox pulling from the table and upon a Dbl-Click it pops open a static form that is Filtered with one of the key fields from the Cross-Tab Table.  Updating information from the Cross-Tab's source table accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentative break-fix solution that worked for me until i can get into the guts and see why the Column Headers are not being pulled from the query fields.

```
If lstCatType.ListIndex >= 0 Then
'Application.Echo False    'Turn off Screen Updating

    Dim crt As String: crt = "crt_CategoryPG"   'Cross-Tab Query
    Dim cttbl As String: cttbl = CreateCTTable(crt) 'Create Table to store the Cross-Tab information
    Dim sql As String: sql = SQLSelect(cttbl)
    Dim flds As DAO.Recordset: Set flds = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    Dim fldwd As String, fldhd As String      'Store the Field Width pattern and Field Header Row
--> fldhd = "-1;-1;Category"
    fldwd = "0"";0"";2.5"""   'Handles `tid` and `cid` columns in the ListBox
    'Assign the number of columns based on the number of fields in CTtable
    lstCategoryPG.ColumnCount = flds.Fields.Count

    Dim fld As Long
    For fld = 3 To (flds.Fields.Count - 1)
        fldwd = fldwd & ";.75"""
-->     fldhd = fldhd & ";" & flds.Fields(fld).Name
    Next
    flds.Close: Set flds = Nothing

    lstCategoryPG.ColumnHeads = True
    lstCategoryPG.ColumnWidths = fldwd

    sql = SQLSelect(cttbl, , ("tid = " & lstCatType.Value))

    lstCategoryPG.Enabled = True
    RefreshControl CurrentDb, lstCategoryPG, sql, , False
--> lstCategoryPG.AddItem fldhd, 0
'Application.Echo True     'Turn Screen Updating back on
End If
```